# Google Cloud Java Client for Stackdriver Trace

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am running my spring boot( 1.4 version) application in GKE.I have added the following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-trace</artifactId>
  <version>0.56.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

I have my authentication setup by enabling stackdriver trace in a service account (key.json file) and set it in my env variable(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS).

I am not seeing any traces from my application,I am not seeing any exception in the logs. Am I missing anything or Is there any working examples for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding that dependency is not sufficient to start collecting traces automatically. You need to add `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See Spring Cloud GCP [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_cloud_sleuth).

Comment: Moreover it works only with springboot version 2.0 or greater